# Flex Add components to Library project from web project

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, custom-component

I have a flex library project, assume this project as basic utility which will be used by multiple other projects. I have many components, such as custom renderer etc which are being used in the library project.

Now, I include *[add source path in the build properties in flex properties]* this library project in a web project. The requirement is to add few project specific components from the web project to the components present in the library project.

So, the basic requirement is to use this library project for multiple other project and be able to add the project specific code through the project.

How can do this? Is there any framework or any solution?

Thanks
Anji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSL library is what you are looking for, it allow you to share class definitions between project.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html

You can also export your components to an swc file (with flash builder, create an Flex Library Project) and include this swc to your differents projects.